# std::string related errors and handling them, c++

Tags: c++

Alright, it might be a stupid question, but I will go ahead and ask anyway.

So, I was wondering, what are all the possible errors associated with std::string usage ? I know a few, for example accessing char at location greater then the std::string size in various std::string functions.

While programming what errors should I keep in mind and place checks on ?

And is there an another way to do following for example, efficiently ?

```
std::string s("some string.");

int i = s.find ( "." );


if (  i != std::string::npos    &&  i + 3 < s.length (  )  ) // <<== this check is what I am talking about
    s.erase ( i + 3 );
```

I have a program, which requires hundreds of such checks, so I was wondering, there was an another way then to do if( some_condition ) each time.

Comment: put it in a function.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore that seems a better option.

Comment: @StudentX: So, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to list every error case for the whole class; just look up the documentation for the functions that you use, which typically lists preconditions.

For example, [cppreference.com's page on `std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

Answer (score 0):

If `i` greater than the string length, an `out_of_range` exception is thrown

Ref:- [std::string::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/)

So you can always catch it !

```
std::string s("some string.");
int i = s.find ( "." );

if (i != std::string::npos)
try 
{
   s.erase ( i + 3 );
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& err) 
{
  std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << err.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: But then, in this case, this approach might not be advisable _if_ input strings with '.'s in arbitrary are perfectly legal and to be expected. If this situation indicates corrupted data or something like that, I agree that throwing the exception and handling it can indeed be the better way.

Comment: unfortunately that's doesn't make life easy :(

Comment: @StudentX well then in that case I'd suggest writing your own `erase` and which put boundary checking on the `pos`